# Spark Scala Aggregate Function to Find number of occurrence of a column value in a group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window, partition

I have following data:

```
group_id    id  name
----        --  ----
G1          1   apple
G1          2   orange
G1          3   apple
G1          4   banana
G1          5   apple
G2          6   orange
G2          7   apple
G2          8   apple
```

I want to find uniqe occurance count in each group. So far I have done this

```
val group = Window.partitionBy("group_id")
newdf.withColumn("name_appeared_count", approx_count_distinct($"name").over(group))
```

I want the result like this:

```
group_id    id  name   name_appeared_count
----        --  ----   -------------------
G1          1   apple       3
G1          2   orange      1
G1          3   apple       3
G1          4   banana      1
G1          5   apple       3
G2          6   orange      1
G2          7   apple       2
G2          8   apple       2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what problems did you encounter with your approach?

Comment: It gives me total unique. For example for G1 I will get 3 for all 5 records, as there are 3 distinct items, and that is correct as per the documentation. But not able to figure out how I can get what I intend to

Comment: Looks like you need to groupby, partitionby by multiple cols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method `approx_count_distinct($"name").over(group)` counts distinct `name` per group, hence isn't what you want based on your expected output.  Using `count("name")` over `partition("group_id", "name")` will produce the wanted counts:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
  ("G1", 1, "apple"),
  ("G1", 2, "orange"),
  ("G1", 3, "apple"),
  ("G1", 4, "banana"),
  ("G1", 5, "apple"),
  ("G2", 6, "orange"),
  ("G2", 7, "apple"),
  ("G2", 8, "apple")
).toDF("group_id", "id", "name")

val group = Window.partitionBy("group_id", "name")

df.
  withColumn("name_appeared_count", count("name").over(group)).
  orderBy("id").
  show
// +--------+---+------+-------------------+
// |group_id| id|  name|name_appeared_count|
// +--------+---+------+-------------------+
// |      G1|  1| apple|                  3|
// |      G1|  2|orange|                  1|
// |      G1|  3| apple|                  3|
// |      G1|  4|banana|                  1|
// |      G1|  5| apple|                  3|
// |      G2|  6|orange|                  1|
// |      G2|  7| apple|                  2|
// |      G2|  8| apple|                  2|
// +--------+---+------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Perfect! So simple thing! Thank you very much Leo C